# Dealing with space in file links using bash

Tags: bash, scripts

I got a problem. Here is my bash script to merge videos with subs:

```
#!/bin/bash 

cd /media/ptrknvk/'TOSHIBA EXT'/Shows/My/'Doctor Who'/

url0='DW s11e0'
url1='DW\ s11e'

for(( i=1; i<11; i++ ))
do
    if ! [ $i -gt 9 ]; 
    then
        mkvmerge -o $url0$i.mkv $url0$i.mkv $url0$i.srt
        rm $url0$i.srt
    else
        mkvmerge -o $url1$i.mkv $url1$i.mkv $url1$i.srt
        rm $url1$i.srt
    fi
done
```

File have names like for example "DW s11e05.mkv" and they actually exist in the directory.

And here is a result:

```
mkvmerge v8.8.0 ('Wind at my back') 64bit
Error: The file 's11e09.mkv' could not be opened for reading: open file error.
rm: cannot remove 'DW': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 's11e09.srt': No such file or directory
mkvmerge v8.8.0 ('Wind at my back') 64bit
Error: The file 's11e10.mkv' could not be opened for reading: open file error.
rm: cannot remove 'DW\': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 's11e10.srt': No such file or directory
```

As you can see '\' before a space doesn't work here. I also tried to use echo, but nothing changed (mb I've used it in a wrong way).

Sorry for my little bit nooby style.

Comment: Yes, but there is cli question. It wasn't bash.

Comment: `bash` *is* the default shell in Ubuntu. Whether in a script or in an interactive shell, quoting rules are exactly the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222). This should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash 

cd /media/ptrknvk/'TOSHIBA EXT'/Shows/My/'Doctor Who'/

url0='DW s11e0'
url1='DW s11e'

for(( i=1; i<11; i++ ))
do
    if ! [ $i -gt 9 ]; 
    then
        mkvmerge -o "$url0$i.mkv" "$url0$i.mkv" "$url0$i.srt" &&
        rm "$url0$i.srt"
    else
        mkvmerge -o "$url1$i.mkv" "$url1$i.mkv" "$url1$i.srt" &&
        rm "$url1$i.srt"
    fi
done
```

Note that I also added a `&&` after each `mkvmerge` command so the `rm` only runs if the `mkvmerge` was successful. You don't want to delete the subtitle file if the merge failed!

That said, although there's absolutely nothing wrong with your approach, I feel you could make it considerable simpler and more elegant using shell globbing instead:

```
#!/bin/bash 

for file in "/media/ptrknvk/TOSHIBA EXT/Shows/My/Doctor Who/"DW*mkv; do
  srtFile=${file//.mkv/.srt}
  mkvmerge -o "$file" "$file" "$srtFile" && rm "$srtFile"
done
```

You don't even need a script for this. You can just run it directly in the terminal as a one liner:

```
for file in "/media/ptrknvk/TOSHIBA EXT/Shows/My/Doctor Who/"DW*mkv; do
  mkvmerge -o "$file" "$file" "${file//.mkv/.srt}" && rm "${file//.mkv/.srt}";
done
```

Answer (score 6):

[Quote variables to prevent word-splitting](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2046). By the way, double-quotes on a whole string is the preferred style.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Also exit if this fails
cd "/media/ptrknvk/TOSHIBA EXT/Shows/My/Doctor Who/" || exit

url0="DW s11e0"
url1="DW s11e"

for (( i=1; i<11; i++ )); do
    # Also why use "not greater-than" when "less-than-or-equal" exists?
    if [ $i -le 9 ]; then
        # Also you can DRY* out this part with variables.
        url="$url0"
    else
        url="$url1"
    fi
    # Also when concatenating variables, it's clearer to use the "${var}" style. **
    f_mkv="${url}${i}.mkv"
    f_srt="${url}${i}.srt"
    mkvmerge -o "$f_mkv" "$f_mkv" "$f_srt"
    rm "$f_srt"
done
```

[Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is really useful for finding problems like this in shell scripts.

* DRY = [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

** Or you could use `printf -v`, but it's not a big improvement in this case. For example

```
printf -v f_mkv "%s%s.mkv" "$url" $i
```